# Jacobi's two-square theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Jacobi's theorem is: the number of ways of representing $N$ as a sum of two squares is $4(d_1(N)-d_3(N))$ where $d_i(N)$ is the number of divisors of $N$ that are of the form $4k+i$.   I was wondering if there is a combinatorial proof of this (involving, of course, the divisors of $N$).  I am working on such a proof but don't want to repeat others' work.

Comment: Papers by Christian Elsholtz could be a good place to start. Also, once you have rewritten the theorem in terms of q-series, you could check the q-series literature, which has a lot of combinatorial proofs.

Comment: Ah -- it's a "Corollaire (Jacobi)" (one of many) in Bodo Lass, *Démonstration de la conjecture de Dumont*, http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~lass/articles/pub13dumontj.pdf . But I'm not sure if you count this proof as combinatorial.

Comment: @darijgrinberg At least, Bodo really works in combinatorics. I think it is a combinatorial proof - well, "Théorie des nombres et Combinatoire".

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  I hadn’t seen the Lass paper  before — wonderfully general.  It uses, like a short proof by Hirschhorn, theta functions and the like.  I’m curious about instead developing the argument of Liouville, Heath-Brown, Zagier proving Fermat’s 2-square theorem (covered in a nice survey by Elsholtz) by, e.g., defining a set and an involution on it and then cleverly using it to show Jacobi’s result.

Comment: Is the Elsholtz survey mentioned above https://www.math.tugraz.at/~elsholtz/WWW/papers/papers30nathanson-new-address3.pdf?  Interesting to hear about Lucas's _Satin squares_ and the movement at the time to write about mathematics for general audiences.

Comment: I think it is equivalent to the Fermat [2-squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) or two the quadratic reciprocity for $(\frac{-1}{p})$

Comment: @BrianHopkins  Yes, that's the paper.